# GParted taking +50h to resize a 900GB partition?

Tags: partition, gparted, hfs+

This is the situation: I have a 1TB hard drive with a 900GB HFS+ partition and 480GB of data. I've decided to shrink that partition to 500GB so I have space for another partition.

However, GParted has been running for 50 hours with no sign of it finishing anytime soon.

The shrinking was to the left, i.e. the free space is added to the right, so in theory, no data move is needed. iotop shows 99% of IO usage by gpartedbin

¿Is this normal? ¿Shouldn't be this type of operations quicker? ¿Is there a way to cancel this operation without loosing data, or a way to recover all files and/or the fs?

Note: Don't want to loose anything, because the disk where I made the backup is now unfortunately dead.

Comment: A rule of thumb is that growing a fs = safe, shrinking = not safe.

Comment: hard to find references but it took ~14 hours for ~100GB over there https://askubuntu.com/a/246864/161981 so let us know if it finished in 9*14=126 hours, and hope it's linear not quadratic ...

Comment: "The free space is added to the right, so in theory, no data move is needed". HFS+ can put files anywhere on the disk, so probably half of the 480GB will be in the second half of the disk and will need to be moved. The moving will involve a lot of seeking, so will not be fast. However 50 hours does seem excessive. How is the disk connected - internal? usb2? usb3?

Comment: A filesystemcheck for a historic filesystem of that size takes 5-10 hours and that checks only meta data. Be prepared that moving data takes a multiple of that.

Comment: @schily Do you mean a filesystemcheck as running `fsck.hfsplus -f [disk]`? If that's the case, that, and some fixes only took 2-3 min.

Comment: it's pretty normal. GParted is extremely dumb when resizing to the left. Tried with ext4, NTFS... and in all cases GParted copies all the data to the left when I expand the partitions to the left. That's why I never use GParted again. All the 3rd party partitioning tools are significantly better than GParted

Comment: This cannot be a full check. I was talking about UFS with a significant number of defect.